# Prove linearly independence by Wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Some questions about the **Wronskian**:

If I want to check out if two functions are linearly dependent I use Wronskian.

My question is : If I find $x_0\in I $ such that $W[f_1,f_2]\neq 0 \implies$ the function are linearly independent ?
But if I find $x_1\in I$ such that $W[f_1,f_2]=0$ it's not enough for proving the functions are linearly independent?

An example :

There is 2 function $f_1(x)=x,f_2(x)=x^2 \implies W[f_1,f_2](x)=x^2.$

$x=0 \implies W[f_1,f_2]=0$

I know both function are linearly independent.

I am a little confused ,Thank you !

Comment: It might help to see the precise statement of the theorem relating the Wronskian and linear independence.

Comment: A necessary condition such that n solutions of ode are span set is $W[y_1,\cdots,y_n](x_0)\neq0$ in some $x_0\in[a,b]$ sorry for my bad english

Comment: I think i get it it is not iff

Comment: This all makes only sense if $f_1, f_2$ are the solutions of the same second order linear homogeneous DE. And additionally if the $x_0$ is not a singular point for the DE.